# While, непоказывать некоторые строчки.

Tags: php, mysql

В общем есть while и вот нужно например если нажать на кнопку Не показывать больше, эта строчка **ТОЛЬКО** у меня не показывалась,а у других показывалась. Вот while:

`while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
$www2 = $row['www'];
$www = '/balance.php?www=' . $www2; 
        echo '<a href="'.$www.'" target="_blank">Выполнить задание </a><br>';
    }`

Знаю нужен MySQL и знаю что нужно заносить исключение, но как это делать?!

Comment: вы сами поняли чего написали ? @ромыч тут с твоей планеты телеграма, переведи пожалуйста.

Comment: шутник :DDD

Answer (score 1):

Нужна таблица исключений.

```
SELECT * `таблица_всех_записей` 
WHERE id NOT IN (
    SELECT id_row FROM `таблица_исключений` WHERE id_user=$id
)
```

Comment: хм, поподробнее пожалуйсто. куда это? php можете написать и соединить с моим кодом? в шапке.

Comment: ясно с вами... не рано еще такие задачи решать?

Comment: Вроде бы понял :) вместо того запроса этот писать

Comment: Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/a6992025/public_html/members.php on line 17.

------------------------------------- Добавлено после
Все! Сделал! 
  $tluser = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `taskrun` WHERE login = '$usernaame'");
$wor = mysql_fetch_array($tluser);
$zapros = $wor['taskrun'];


    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `tasks_like` WHERE id NOT IN ($zapros)");

Answer (score 0):

Можно ввести отдельную таблицу для игнорирования всего этого, и составить запрос, который будет игнорировать содержащиеся в ней записи для текущего юзера.

Comment: Не могли бы вы написать запрос?